# Entity Framework database-first code generation

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql, sql-server-2016

This code:

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION 
SET LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION=ON
```

makes my Entity Framework code generation very fast.

However I have also learned that I need to set it off my code generation completes.

Can some one explain what actually the code does? I went through google but could not find the understanding.

I am using SQL Server 2016 and Entity Framework v6

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a known issue with new CE and the reverse engineering queries in EF. It also looks like the issue is specific to SQL 2016 and has bounced back and forth between the SQL team and the EF team.

The first fix posted was the one you mention in your post, ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION=ON

After this it looks like updating statistics on tables is a viable solution.

Check out this link - https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/issues/57